# recursively reverse a linked list without a global variable

Tags: c++, linked-list

I wonder why passing the second parameter `Node** fhead` causes a segfault? `Node` has an `int` value and a next pointer pointing to the next `Node`.

Here is my code:

```
void reverse(Node* head, Node** fhead) {
    if (!head->next)
    {
        fhead = &head;
        return;
    }

    reverse(head->next, fhead);
    head->next->next = head;
    head->next = 0;
}

int main() 
{
   Node a = {1, 0};
   Node b = {2, &a};
   Node c = {3, &b};

   Node** fhead;
   reverse(&c, fhead);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you have a `List` class?

Comment: `fhead` should be a `Node*` and passed as `&fhead` if you need to change what it points to (and should definitely be initialized to `nullptr`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two very small but serious problems.

First,

```
fhead = &head;
```

assigns a value to the parameter, so that change will not be visible outside of the function.

This works exactly like

```
void f(int x) 
{
    x = 0;
}
```

Just like you would do when you pass e.g. a pointer to an `int`,

```
void f(int* x) 
{
    *x = 0;
}
```

you need to assign to the object that the pointer points to:

```
*fhead = head;
```

Second, you need to pass a valid pointer to a variable:

```
Node* fhead = 0;
reverse(&c, &fhead);
```

(The initialisation isn't strictly necessary, but it's a good idea to initialise variables.)

With those two changes, your code works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You have a little mistake in the recurssion termination. You should set `*fhead` to `head` and not assigning it with `&head` (Which will just change `fhead` locally in the funciton):

```
if (!head->next)
{
    *fhead = head;
    return;
}
```

Comment: This is right. I am changing the pointer value instead moving the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
    if (head == null || head.next == null)
        return head;
    ListNode p = reverseList(head.next);
    head.next.next = head;
    head.next = null;
    return p;
}
```

One can assume ListNode definition

```
class ListNode{
  int val;
  ListNode next; 
  public ListNode(int val){
     this.val = val;
     this.next = null;
  }
}
```